# Configuring .NET SerialPort based off of a signaling rate of 38400 bit/sec

Tags: .net, serial-port, baud-rate

I am having trouble communicating with a serial device. I am having trouble determining with the baud rate should be. The documentation says signaling rate is 38400 bit/sec.

Here is the documentation for the serial port.

[image: Documentation]

How does this translate to the .NET `SerialPort` class?

```
using (var port = new SerialPort("COM16"))
{
    port.BaudRate = 9800;       // ??
    port.Parity = Parity.Even;  // ??

    // anything else? anything wrong?

    port.Open(); //go!
}
```

Comment: Improperly they are considered to be equivalent. 1 baud/s == 1 bit/s, 38400 bauds/s == 38400 bits/s. **improperly**!

Comment: @xanatos, even with the even parity?

Comment: Why would you set Baudrate = 9800 when the docs say 38400???  Set the StopBits, DataBits and Handshake properties as well.

Comment: @HansPassant, I thought the baud rate was different than the bits per-second, because it may take more than one bit (start/stop/parity) to describe a single 8-bit byte. No?

http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/117241/baud-rate-calculation

Comment: @HansPassant, also, I'm not typically a serial/com developer. I can write/read bytes all day, but I don't understand modem communication enough to translate the documents correctly to the .NET SerialPort type.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to put all of your code in the `using` block, you can close the port explicitly at the end.

```
SerialPort port = new SerialPort();
port.PortName = "COM16";
port.BaudRate = 38400; // Baud rate = bits per second
port.DataBits = 8; // unnecessary as 8 is the default
port.Parity = Parity.Even; // unnecessary as Even is the default
port.StopBits = StopBits.One; // unnecessary as One is the default
```

If you still can't connect, try connecting with [Termite](https://www.compuphase.com/software_termite.htm), which is a serial port terminal program. If you have to choose settings like "DTR/DTS" to get it to work, then you might need settings like this:

```
port.DtrEnable = true;
port.RtsEnable = true;
```

Then open your port.

```
port.Open();

port.DataReceived += OnRx; // Add the event handler for receiving data
```

The easiest way to read asynchronously is to create an event handler and pass the data back to a variable that the method has access to.

```
List<string> rx = new List<string>(); // the event handler stores the received data here

// Add this method to your class to read asynchronously.
protected void OnRx(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e) {
    while (port.BytesToRead > 0) {
        try {
            rx.Add(port.ReadLine());
        } catch (Exception) { }    
    }
}
```

Close your port

```
port.Close();
```

Also check out the `SerialPort` [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport(v=vs.110).aspx).